# Discord.js Find if the person who reacted to a message has a specific role

Tags: node.js, discord.js

When a user reacts to a message I need to know if they have 1 of a few accepted roles. The accepted roles are:

```
const roles = ['Founder', 'The Board', 'Community Manager', 'Botmaster', 'Staff', 'Deputy Mods'];
```

Then, when a user reacts to a message I just want to log if at least 1 of their roles matches at least 1 of the accepted roles. For right now I'm just trying to do it for 1 specific role:

```
console.log(reaction.message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Bot Master'));
```

The problem currently is that regardless of who reacts it always prints the following:

```
Role {
  guild: <ref *1> Guild {
    id: '686238814749851697',
    name: 'iTero Gaming',
    icon: 'a_c9d01a7737f0e70197a0ad54de54f018',
    features: [
      'AUTO_MODERATION',
      'GUILD_SERVER_GUIDE',
      'TEXT_IN_VOICE_ENABLED',
      'INVITE_SPLASH',
      'GUILD_ONBOARDING_HAS_PROMPTS',
      'WELCOME_SCREEN_ENABLED',
      'RAID_ALERTS_ENABLED',
      'COMMUNITY',
      'GUILD_ONBOARDING',
      'NEWS',
      'THREE_DAY_THREAD_ARCHIVE',
      'ANIMATED_ICON',
      'GUILD_ONBOARDING_EVER_ENABLED'
    ],
    commands: GuildApplicationCommandManager {
      permissions: [ApplicationCommandPermissionsManager],
      guild: [Circular *1]
    },
    members: GuildMemberManager { guild: [Circular *1] },
    channels: GuildChannelManager { guild: [Circular *1] },
    bans: GuildBanManager { guild: [Circular *1] },
    roles: RoleManager { guild: [Circular *1] },
    presences: PresenceManager {},
    voiceStates: VoiceStateManager { guild: [Circular *1] },
    stageInstances: StageInstanceManager { guild: [Circular *1] },
    invites: GuildInviteManager { guild: [Circular *1] },
    scheduledEvents: GuildScheduledEventManager { guild: [Circular *1] },
    autoModerationRules: AutoModerationRuleManager { guild: [Circular *1] },
    available: true,
    shardId: 0,
    splash: null,
    banner: null,
    description: null,
    verificationLevel: 1,
    vanityURLCode: null,
    nsfwLevel: 0,
    premiumSubscriptionCount: 3,
    discoverySplash: null,
    memberCount: 989,
    large: true,
    premiumProgressBarEnabled: true,
    applicationId: null,
    afkTimeout: 300,
    afkChannelId: null,
    systemChannelId: null,
    premiumTier: 1,
    widgetEnabled: null,
    widgetChannelId: null,
    explicitContentFilter: 2,
    mfaLevel: 1,
    joinedTimestamp: 1679960457532,
    defaultMessageNotifications: 1,
    systemChannelFlags: SystemChannelFlagsBitField { bitfield: 6 },
    maximumMembers: 250000,
    maximumPresences: null,
    maxVideoChannelUsers: 25,
    approximateMemberCount: null,
    approximatePresenceCount: null,
    vanityURLUses: null,
    rulesChannelId: '1026887740471660634',
    publicUpdatesChannelId: '1026885264758546442',
    preferredLocale: 'en-US',
    ownerId: '513795277841235983',
    emojis: GuildEmojiManager { guild: [Circular *1] },
    stickers: GuildStickerManager { guild: [Circular *1] }
  },
  icon: null,
  unicodeEmoji: null,
  id: '1070012259625074689',
  name: 'Bot Master',
  color: 3269542,
  hoist: true,
  rawPosition: 22,
  permissions: PermissionsBitField { bitfield: 1000831569473n },
  managed: false,
  mentionable: false,
  tags: {}
}
```

I would think that if the `.find` method didn't find the role then it would not print at all, but it is printing every single time.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what happens if you change the `=`  for `===` on `.find`?

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(reaction.message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name = 'Bot Master'));
```

Looks like you are using `=` instead of `===` when comparing the retrieved role name to the string. Changing `=` to `===` should fix your problem.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect the changes but I did add this. Rookie mistake, my b. However, it did not fix the problem. Now the result is just always undefined. Any other suggestions?